ABCPDF Cannot close metafile, a windows error occurred indicating not enough memory
I am getting the following error when creating large PDFs from HTML using ABCPDF:
ABCPDF Cannot close metafile
A windows error occurred indicating not enough memory (8).
The PDFs themselves aren't huge (mainly text and save to under 2MB), but I do appreciate they run to over 100 pages.  Smaller PDFs work just fine.  The system itself has about 8GB of RAM free and plenty of space for any temporary files at the time of the error.  Before experimenting with the upgrade route (I am on version 11, the latest is 13), does anyone know of a work around or a system setting that might be incorrectly set that is stopping ABCPDF from accessing the memory it needs to get the job done.
